# Are there limits to If And Then formula in GoogleSheets?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I've got an issue with the following formula...

```
=IF(AND(D18<=72,G18="Defensive"),2000,IF(AND(D18<=74,G18="Defensive"),5000,IF(AND(D18=75,G18="Defensive"),10000,IF(AND(D18=76,G18="Defensive"),20000,IF(AND(D18=77,G18="Defensive"),40000,IF(AND(D18=78,G18="Defensive"),60000,IF(AND(D18=79,G18="Defensive"),70000,IF(AND(D18=80,G18="Defensive"),80000,IF(AND(D18=81,G18="Defensive"),90000,IF(AND(D18=82,G18="Defensive"),100000,IF(AND(D18=83,G18="Defensive"),110000,IF(AND(D18=84,G18="Defensive"),120000,IF(AND(D18=85,G18="Defensive"),140000,IF(AND(D18>=86,G18="Defensive"),160000,IF(AND(D18>=88,G18="Defensive",1800000,IF(AND(D18<=72,G18="Attacking"),2000,IF(AND(D18<=74,G18="Attacking"),5000,IF(AND(D18=75,G18="Attacking"),15000,IF(AND(D18=76,G18="Attacking"),25000,IF(AND(D18=77,G18="Attacking"),50000,IF(AND(D18=78,G18="Attacking"),70000,IF(AND(D18=79,G18="Attacking"),80000,IF(AND(D18=80,G18="Attacking"),85000,IF(AND(D18=81,G18="Attacking"),95000,IF(AND(D18=82,G18="Attacking"),110000,IF(AND(D18=83,G18="Attacking"),120000,IF(AND(D18=84,G18="Attacking"),135000,IF(AND(D18=85,G18="Attacking"),160000,IF(AND(D18>=86,G18="Attacking"),210000,IF(AND(D18>=88,G18="Attacking"),230000,0)))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Once it reaches the first IF AND statement that includes G18="Attacking" I get a Wrong Number of Arguments error, expecting 2 or 3 but getting 1. That doesn't make sense to me and I can't see any issues. When I test just those with G18="Attacking" on their own all works fine.

Is there a limit to these that I don't know about?

Here's a link to where we're testing something

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, indeed you forgot a parenthesis in one of the `AND`s formulas:

```
=IF(AND(D18<=72,G18="Defensive"),2000,IF(AND(D18<=74,G18="Defensive"),5000,IF(AND(D18=75,G18="Defensive"),10000,IF(AND(D18=76,G18="Defensive"),20000,IF(AND(D18=77,G18="Defensive"),40000,IF(AND(D18=78,G18="Defensive"),60000,IF(AND(D18=79,G18="Defensive"),70000,IF(AND(D18=80,G18="Defensive"),80000,IF(AND(D18=81,G18="Defensive"),90000,IF(AND(D18=82,G18="Defensive"),100000,IF(AND(D18=83,G18="Defensive"),110000,IF(AND(D18=84,G18="Defensive"),120000,IF(AND(D18=85,G18="Defensive"),140000,IF(AND(D18>=86,G18="Defensive"),160000,IF(AND(D18>=88,G18="Defensive"),1800000,IF(AND(D18<=72,G18="Attacking"),2000,IF(AND(D18<=74,G18="Attacking"),5000,IF(AND(D18=75,G18="Attacking"),15000,IF(AND(D18=76,G18="Attacking"),25000,IF(AND(D18=77,G18="Attacking"),50000,IF(AND(D18=78,G18="Attacking"),70000,IF(AND(D18=79,G18="Attacking"),80000,IF(AND(D18=80,G18="Attacking"),85000,IF(AND(D18=81,G18="Attacking"),95000,IF(AND(D18=82,G18="Attacking"),110000,IF(AND(D18=83,G18="Attacking"),120000,IF(AND(D18=84,G18="Attacking"),135000,IF(AND(D18=85,G18="Attacking"),160000,IF(AND(D18>=86,G18="Attacking"),210000,IF(AND(D18>=88,G18="Attacking"),230000,0))))))))))))))))))))))))))))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You have a typo here:

```
AND(D18>=88,G18="Defensive",1800000,IF(
```

The `AND` function doesn't take so many arguments, which is why the error message is what it is. You've likely missed the `)`.

How did I find this, you may ask. I appended newlines after each `(` and before each `)` (simple automatic search-replace in Vim), then used automatic indentation in Vim. After this, in no-wrap mode, the whole chain looks like a nice stairs, with only the above faulty part sticking out.

Answer (score 0):

This is the case when you have to think hard about whether there is no easier way to achieve a result.

For example, you could create a lookup table and then use a very simple formula that would allow for easy addition and debugging:

```
=LOOKUP(D2,$I$2:$I$16,INDEX($J$2:$K$16,0,(G2="Def")+(G2="Att")*2))
```

[image]

**P.S.**

There is a condition in your formula that will never be met:

```
...IF(AND(D18>=86,G18="Defensive"),160000,IF(AND(D18>=88,G18="Defensive"),1800000...
```